# Short sci-fi film about a robot who saves a blind little girl?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Probably less than 10 years old – a little girl is on a planet inhospitable to human life and a medical AI helps her from orbit. I saw it on YouTube, can't find it now searching on "blind girl medical robot" and maybe it is no longer there.

What is interesting/touching is the robot is itself damaged and its normal function is to directly do medical procedures but it (as of course in many stories) is able to do more than originally intended,

Comment: Ringing vague bells… maybe a story from *Love and Robots*?

Comment: Not L&R because older than that, I thinks.

Comment: Trying to find it, but pretty sure it's one of the shorts on the DUST Youtube channel  https://www.youtube.com/c/watchdust/videos